# How to see how far is the disk overwriting in the gnome-disk-utility?

Tags: 18.04, disk, gnome-disk-utility

I used the `gnome-disk-utility` to overwrite and encrypt an old 2TB disk. The process is running now already for two days.

[image: screenshot gnome-disk-utility]

Is there any way to see how far it progressed?

---

**UPDATE**

It's done! So it took roughly 2.5 days with an average writing rate of 91,8 MB/s (100 samples via USB3)... just if anybody wonder!

Comment: I doubt it but remember it's 2TB so you have to be patient!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I'm patient, but still curious ;)

Answer (score 1):

*That's not total a correct answer to my question but it could help...*

I found this little online calculator: http://www.calctool.org/CALC/prof/computing/transfer_time Its nice to get an idea about how long it will take. It had calculated ~ 2 days to write everything 1x over.

[image: calctool]